# How FileLock can be used in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

In `Java` we can use `FileLock` to handle the synchronization between different process, but how to use FileLock with `withWriter` in `Groovy`?

For exmaple I have the following code:

```
File file = new File("./test.txt")
file.withWriter{ writer -> 
      writer.writeLine 'testing'
}
```

How to use FileLock in Groovy with `withWriter` to provide synchronization between different process?

And beside of that, are there any other ways can be used?

Comment: Does this gist help at all https://gist.github.com/pditommaso/4616192e50cd333487211d1e37e81d58? You can just use the Java NIO FileLock class in your groovy code. Test that you have the actual file lock then use writer as in your example to write to it

Comment: thanks, but can it be used with withWriter() together?

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy meta programming

Through the wonders of Groovy meta programming (and the gist shared by dawogfather), here's an easy to use example.

```
import java.nio.channels.FileLock
// java.io.RandomAccessFile
// java.io.File

java.io.File.metaClass.getTextWithLock { ->
    FileLock lock
    final RandomAccessFile fileaccess = new RandomAccessFile(getAbsoluteFile(), 'rw')
    String contents
    try {
        while( !(lock=fileaccess.getChannel().tryLock()) )  {
            // sleep up to half a second
            sleep(new Random().nextInt(500))
        }
        contents = getText()
    } finally {
        lock?.close()
        fileaccess.close()
    }
    contents ?: ''
}
java.io.File.metaClass.withLockedWriter { Closure body ->
    if(!exists()) {
        createNewFile()
    }
    FileLock lock
    final RandomAccessFile fileaccess = new RandomAccessFile(getAbsoluteFile(), 'rw')
    try {
        while( !(lock=fileaccess.getChannel().tryLock()) )  {
            // sleep up to half a second
            sleep(new Random().nextInt(500))
        }
        withWriter(body)
    } finally {
        lock?.close()
        fileaccess.close()
    }
}

(new File('/tmp/foo')).withLockedWriter { Writer w ->
    w << 'hello'
}

new File('/tmp/foo').getTextWithLock()
```

## As a Groovy Class

```
import java.nio.channels.FileLock
// java.io.RandomAccessFile
// java.io.File

class LockableFile extends File {
    LockableFile(String s) {
        super(s)
    }
    String getTextWithLock() {
        FileLock lock
        final RandomAccessFile fileaccess = new RandomAccessFile(getAbsoluteFile(), 'rw')
        String contents
        try {
            while( !(lock=fileaccess.getChannel().tryLock()) )  {
                // sleep up to half a second
                sleep(new Random().nextInt(500))
            }
            contents = getText()
        } finally {
            lock?.close()
            fileaccess.close()
        }
        contents ?: ''
    }
    Writer withLockedWriter(Closure body) {
        if(!exists()) {
            createNewFile()
        }
        FileLock lock
        final RandomAccessFile fileaccess = new RandomAccessFile(getAbsoluteFile(), 'rw')
        try {
            while( !(lock=fileaccess.getChannel().tryLock()) )  {
                // sleep up to half a second
                sleep(new Random().nextInt(500))
            }
            withWriter(body)
        } finally {
            lock?.close()
            fileaccess.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Which then you would import and use it in a similar way.

```
new LockableFile('/tmp/foo').withLockedWriter { Writer w ->
    w << 'hello'
}

new LockableFile('/tmp/foo').getTextWithLock()
```